# Interface fulfilled by struct embedding

Tags: go

I'm confused by my experiments with the following program, related to fulfilling interface with struct embedding, with named types and pointer receivers, respectively:

```
package main

import "fmt"

type MyInt interface {
    mytest()
}

type Base struct {
}

func (b *Base) mytest() {
    fmt.Println("From base")
}

type Derived struct {
    Base
}

type Derived2 struct {
    *Base
}

func main() {
    // Only this one has problem
    // However, if we change mytest's receiver from *Base to Base, all the four assignments are OK
    var _ MyInt = Derived{}

    // OK
    var _ MyInt = &Derived{}
    var _ MyInt = Derived2{}
    var _ MyInt = &Derived2{}
}
```

See the comments in the code for my confusions. Are there any principal ways to explain them?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the [Go language specification](https://golang.org/ref/spec#Struct_types):

> Given a struct type S and a type named T, promoted methods are
>   included in the method set of the struct as follows:
>
> - If S contains an anonymous field T, the method sets of S and *S both
>     include promoted methods with receiver T.
> - The method set of *S also
>     includes promoted methods with receiver *T.
> - If S contains an anonymous
>     field *T, the method sets of S and *S both include promoted methods
>     with receiver T or *T.

The case that doesn't work in your code:

```
var _ MyInt = Derived{}
```

Here the method set of `Derived` (which contains an anonymous field `Base`) includes methods of `Base` by rule 1. Since `mytest` is a method of `*Base` and not `Base`, it's promoted to a method of `*Derived` (by the second rule), but not of `Derived`.

Why is it like that? Well, it's similar to the rule for method sets of structs: methods of `T` are also methods of `T*`, but not vice-versa. That's because a method of a pointer receiver can expect to be able to mutate its receiver, but a method of a non-pointer receiver can't.

Comment: This explains it but I don't understand the motivation behind these rules.

Comment: @M.Tong I added a paragraph explaining what I think the motivation is.

Answer (score 0):

As per your code function mytest can be called on receiver which pointer to Base.

Struct Derived inherits/embeds Base and Derived2 inherits/embeds *Base i.e. pointer to base.

For

1. var _MyInt = &Derived2{}: Here pointer of Derived2 is created and since Dervied2 inherits from *Base calling mytest on _MyInt will work
2. var _MyInt = Derived2{}: Instance of Derived2 is created and since Dervied2 inherits from *Base calling mytest on _MyInt will work
3. var _MyInt = &Derived{}: Here pointer of Derived is created and since Dervied inherits from Base calling mytest on _MyInt will work
4. var _MyInt = Derived{}: Instance of Derived is created and since Dervied inherits from Base calling mytest on _MyInt will not work has pointer to Base is expected.

You rightly pointed out that changing receiver from *Base to Base will work because Go will be able recognize Object from pointer and will be able to call mytest.

As per golang specification
A type may have a method set associated with it. The method set of an interface type is its interface. The method set of any other type T consists of all methods declared with receiver type T. The method set of the corresponding pointer type *T is the set of all methods declared with receiver *T or T (that is, it also contains the method set of T).

Hope this helps